# How to prove the approximation properties of taylor polynomials?

Tags: calculus

This problem is from Thomas's Calculus:
[image]

The following is one answer I find:
 [image]

But after applying L’Hôpital’s rule, I don't understand why: 
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f'(x) - b_1 -2b_2(x-a) -3b_3(x-a)^2 - \cdots - nb_n(x-a)^n}{n(x-a)^{n-1}} = 0 \Rightarrow b_1 = f'(a) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{E(x)}{(x-a)^n}  = 0
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{E(x)}{(x-a)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{E(x)}{(x-a)^n} \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\  (x-a)^{n-1}  = 0\cdot 0 = 0.
\end{align}
Now, since we assume $E(x) = f(x) -g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{E(x)}{(x-a)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\ [f'(x)-g'(x)] = f'(a) -g'(a) = 0.
\end{align}
But since 
\begin{align}
g(x) = b_0+b_1(x-a) + b_2(x-a)^2+\ldots + b_n(x-a)^n
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
g'(x) = b_1+ 2b_2(x-a) + \ldots + nb_n(x-a)^{n-1} \ \ \implies \ \ \ f'(a) = g'(a) = b_1. 
\end{align}
Likewise, you can show $f^{(k)}(a) = k! b_k$.